# swift Weird reaction towards contentsFromUrl

Tags: php, ios, mysql, swift, nsdata

I have a php file in placed in my host. I use it to access the mySQL database.

I have two files of php, one for **INSERT** and one for **SELECT**. Both work when I use the url in my browser.

```
domain.com/insert.php?query=insert%20into%20user%20(user,pass,email,phone)%20values('test','test','test','test');

domain.com/select.php?query=SELECT%20`id`%20FROM%20`user`%20WHERE%20user%20=%20'user'%20and%20pass%20=%20'pass';
```

both work correctly when I use them in browser. I have a swift app that sends and receives data through the php file by `contentsFromUrl`.

```
let strURL = "http://domain.com/insert.php?query=insert%20into%20user%20(user,pass,email,phone)%20values('test','test','test','test');"
var dataURL = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: strURL)!);
```

This works properly and I can easily insert data to my database.
I have another code for selecting data from database, using the url. The same way is went.

```
let strURL = "http://domain.com/select.php?query=SELECT%20`id`%20FROM%20`user`%20WHERE%20user%20=%20'user'%20and%20pass%20=%20'pass';"
var dataURL = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: strURL)!);
```

When I run this code, it says `fatal error: unexpectedly received nil`

When I copy this url from my swift code and paste it in my browser, it does it correctly and gives me the data I want !!

Pure stupidness, I mean what is the difference between to strings? both php files return  a string but it seems that when i use the select statement, it doesn't receive anything :|

Please help me, its driving me crazy :\

Answer (score 1):

URLs must begin with their protocol (http or https). The initialization with the second URL is returning nil and you are forcefully unwrapping it: `NSURL(string: strURL)!`. That is where you are getting the crash. It is returning nil because it is not being passed a valid URL.

Add an "http://" to the beginning of the URL and it will work:

```
let strURL = "http://domain.com/select.php?query=SELECT%20`id`%20FROM%20`user`%20WHERE%20user%20=%20'user'%20and%20pass%20=%20'pass';"
var dataURL = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: strURL)!);
```

Note: this URL works in your browser because the browser is nice and assumes "http" if you do not specify a protocol.

Comment: I have done what you said. It will not work. I mean, i copy the text and paste it in the browser (with http://) and it gives me a result!

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate your link using stringByAddingPercentEncoding:

```
let strLink = "http://domain.com/select.php?query=SELECT%20`id`%20FROM%20`user`%20WHERE%20user%20=%20'user'%20and%20pass%20=%20'pass';"
let linkComponents = strLink.componentsSeparatedByString("?")
if let query = linkComponents.last?.stringByRemovingPercentEncoding {
    print(query)   // "query=SELECT `id` FROM `user` WHERE user = 'user' and pass = 'pass';"
    if let queryPercentEncoded = query.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet()) {
        print(queryPercentEncoded)   // "query=SELECT%20%60id%60%20FROM%20%60user%60%20WHERE%20user%20=%20'user'%20and%20pass%20=%20'pass';"
        let linkPercentEncoded = (linkComponents.first ?? "") + "?" + queryPercentEncoded
        if let strURL = NSURL(string: linkPercentEncoded ) {
            print(true)
            // note you should download your data asynchronously using NSURLSession dataTaskFromURL
            if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL:  strURL) {
                print(data.length)
            }
        }
    }
}
```